# ffmpeg - Video longer than audio after having combined image and audio to video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I wrote code to combine several audio files with 1 image, into WebM video. (audio1 combined with default jpg, audio2 combined with default jpg, etc).

The problem is that after this, video length is 25 seconds superior to audio length (so audio cuts 25 seconds before the end of the video).

Is there a way to stop the video at the exact same time of the audio? Here is the code I used (I launch a BAT command file)

```
@echo off  
for %%F in (*.ogg) do (  
  ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i "default.jpg" -i "%%F" -acodec libopus -b:a 384k -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -speed 4 -vf scale=1280x720 -shortest "%%F.webm" 
)
```

Comment: Any help? Very important.

Comment: It's a bug, See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5456

Comment: I already saw that, it doesn't help. I will not use a 2012 version of ffmpeg.. so is it possible to remove the last 25 seconds of video for each created media with ffmpeg ? Like join each audio with a specific image to make several videos and then remove last 25 seconds ?

Comment: Saving to format .TS will work; or increasing framerate to 25+ will do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to upload game soundtracks and I just need a still image with audio, and uploading videos with +25 fps will be hard for me since I don't have a good connection. That's why I put 1 fps, to reduce file size then I can upload faster. Also, WebM produces smaller files than TS If I'm not wrong. So, do you have other ideas ??

Comment: For small size, skip lossless. If you're uploading to a 3rd-party service, they'll re-encode it in a lossy manner anyway. Use codec x264 with framerate 25, and add `-crf 16 -x264opts no-scenecut:keyint=9999`

Comment: Ok, thank you. Last question, is there any way to leave my code as-is (my first code with WebM) and just add something to remove the last 25 seconds of video for each produced video ? It's always 25 seconds of no sound. There's something to do with -sseof no ?

Comment: Not possible automatically. You can probe the duration of the audio beforehand and use `-t <dur>` instead of `-shortest`. `ffprobe audio.file -show_entries format=duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a solution of sorts:

First, run your original command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i "default.jpg" -i "%%F"
      -acodec libopus -b:a 384k -vcodec libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -speed 4 -vf scale=1280x720 -shortest temp.webm
```

and then

```
ffmpeg -i temp.webm -c copy -fflags shortest -max_interleave_delta 10000000000 -flush_packets 0 "%%F.webm"
```

This produces a file 1 second longer than the audio duration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! Alternate solution (it's now solved), replacing -b:a 384k by "copy" works. Creating media with combined image/audio seems to have sync audio/video length when you leave the audio source quality as-is, without reencoding. That was the problem.